# Using a different MySQL database engine

Tags: mysql, macos, innodb, myisam

I am having problems trying to use a different MySQL database engine.  (I want to change from MyISAM to InnoDB)

/etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

It appears that it is not installed?  If that is true, how can I install InnoDB?

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                   | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                        | NO           | NO   | NO         | 
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                     | NO           | NO   | NO         | 
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables | NO           | NO   | NO         | 
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance    | NO           | NO   | NO         | 
+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am on Mac OS 10.5 and I am using MySQL version 5.1.35.

Comment: You're using a very old release of MySQL from 2009! I suggest you upgrade at least to MySQL 5.5, where InnoDB is by default enabled and set to the default storage engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pluggable-storage.html

You'll need to locate download the appropriate build of the InnoDB plugin.